# Creating a vector of dates from the previous week (Monday to Sunday)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a vector of dates from the previous week (Monday to Sunday) but unsure of how to do this due to problems reverting back to last Monday. So what I'm after is the last full week of dates like so;

2023-08-21 through to 2023-08-27

To do this I thought a while loop would work to revert the day of the week back to Monday but that wouldn't work as it would just stop at the first Monday which in this case is the 28th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = Sys.Date()
while(weekdays(m)!="Monday") { m = m - 1 }
liste <- c(m-7, m-6, m-5, m-4, m-3, m-2, m-1)
print(liste)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use `floor_date` function from `lubridate`. Here you can specify today's date, and round to the nearest day of the week, with the week start specified as "1" (Monday). Subtracting seven will refer to the previous Monday. Then, use `seq` to create a vector dates, with a length of 7 days starting with the previous Monday.

```
library(lubridate)

today <- Sys.Date()

seq.Date(from = floor_date(today, "week", 1) - 7, 
         by = "day", 
         length.out = 7)
```

**Output**

```
"2023-08-21" "2023-08-22" "2023-08-23" "2023-08-24" "2023-08-25" "2023-08-26" "2023-08-27"
```